# How to hide suggestionView without having to delete characters in a RadAutoCompleteTextView using Nativescript Vue js

Tags: nativescript-vue

Currently when you start typing RadAutoCompleteTextView element using Nativescript Vue js the suggestionView Element is displayed. The only way to make the suggestionView to disappear is to delete each character in the field. I need to be able to make the suggestionView not display when i clear the RadAutoCompleteTextView field. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What code do you have currently?

Comment: I have tried several things. I did discover however if you click somewhere on the page while the SuggestionView is displaying it will disappear however Im working on mimicking that now. It seems its not easy to trigger a click or some other gesture event in nativescript easily. As for the code it a proprietary project im working on and unable to show the code

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and I solved it with setting the suggestion view height to 1 on the textChanged event when the text doesn't exist in the items array